# Select by customer, the name of the most expensive product of his most recent order

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables:

- orders containing order_id, order_date, customer_id, product_id, revenue
- products containing product_id and product_name

What I'd like to do is to select by customer, the name of the most expensive product of his most recent order

```
SELECT MAX(o.ORDER_DATE), MAX(o.REVENUE) , PRODUCT_NAME
FROM orders o 
JOIN products p ON o.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_NAME
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, and the result that you want

Comment: @Pauline . . . Your stated data model has no information on the price of products.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MAX(o.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) order_date, 
       FIRST_VALUE(o.revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                                    ORDER BY order_date DESC, revenue DESC) revenue, 
       FIRST_VALUE(product_name) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                                       ORDER BY order_date DESC, revenue DESC) product_name       
FROM orders o 
JOIN products p USING (product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stated data model has no information on the "most expensive product".  Let me assume that `products` actually has a column such as "price".

I think I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT op.*
FROM (SELECT o.*, p.*
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.customer_id ORDER BY o.order_date DESC, p.price DESC) as seqnum
      FROM orders o JOIN
           products p
           ON o.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
     ) op
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per customer.  If there is a tie and you want all the rows, change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `RANK()`.  Note that this method gives you a lot of flexibility over which columns you want to include in the result set.